# NGINX opensource: ensure communication encrypted between balancer and nodes

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I'm setting up a load balancer that has to communicate with the other nodes using TLS. This is important since back-end nodes are not in a private network. The configuration is the one below.

The result is that Nginx returns **502 bad gateway**, and Nginx seems not able to redirect to my domains. Furthermore, since I'm using **open source** version, I **cannot** use the **resolve** keyword inside upstream configuration. How can I change this configuration to have Nginx encrypt data between example.com -> backendX.example.com?

NOTICE: if I use IPs instead of URLs into the upstream block the load balancing works, but I don't think it is encrypted

ERROR:

```
*3 upstream SSL certificate verify error: (2:unable to get issuer certificate) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 0.0.0.0, server: lb.example.com
```

RESULT of `openssl s_client -connect backend1.example.com`:

```
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = backend1.example.com
   i:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
 1 s:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
   i:C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
 2 s:C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
   i:O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
```

```
upstream example.com{
   least_conn;
   server backend1.example.com;
   server backend2.example.com;
}

server {

        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name lb.example.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass https://example.com;

                proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/.../chain.pem;
                proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
                proxy_ssl_verify       on;
                proxy_ssl_verify_depth 2;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/.../fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/.../privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

#### NGINX -T
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;
    resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=30s;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

upstream example.com{
   least_conn;
   server backend1.example.com;
   server backend2.example.com;
}

server {

        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name lb.example.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass https://example.com;

                proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/.../chain.pem;
                proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
                proxy_ssl_verify       on;
                proxy_ssl_verify_depth 2;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/.../fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/.../privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = lb.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name lb.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}

# configuration file /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf:
# This file contains important security parameters. If you modify this file
# manually, Certbot will be unable to automatically provide future security
# updates. Instead, Certbot will print and log an error message with a path to
# the up-to-date file that you will need to refer to when manually updating
# this file.

ssl_session_cache shared:le_nginx_SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout 1440m;
ssl_session_tickets off;

ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA";
```

**nginx -t**
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Comment: why do you use https and a port for the upstreams? a port is only needed in case you have none standard ports used

Comment: @djdomi I also tried without specifying ports. It was a trial I made to ensure that wasn't the problem

Comment: both backends can be resolved?

Comment: @djdomi Yes, they are both reachable with normal browsing using their url

Comment: @djdomi I fixed the example. Anyway, the domain used by my DNS and the domain used by the other nodes are all different

Comment: please share the output of nginx -t and afterwards nginx -T of each other server because IMHO the ssl cert part looks strange [look here as example](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-load-balancing-with-ssl-termination)

Comment: @djdomi Added below. The other back-end nodes are pre-existing servers on apache that we used for a lot of time. I was just trying to use nginx as load balancer to put it in between. If I remove URLs and use IPs in upstream everything works fine, but the problem of using IPs is that I don't know wether the communication is encrypted

Comment: You need to have specified a `resolver` but I don't see one anywhere. According to the [docs](https://nginx.org/r/resolver), these must go in `http`, `server` or `location` blocks.

Comment: There is (in my http settings)! But it still doesn't work

Comment: OK, I see it now. I looked for your error_log entries but I can't find them in your post. Please try making another request and then post the new error_log entries.

Comment: @MichaelHampton found out the issue but not how to solve it: during SSL handshakes I'm not sending CA trusted certificate. How can I fix it?  ERROR: *3 upstream SSL certificate verify error: (2:unable to get issuer certificate) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 0.0.0.0, server: lb.example.com,

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have changed trusted CA cert with /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt; and now the error is *1  upstream SSL certificate does not match "upstream-name" while SSL handshaking to upstream